# Folder cannot be found by absolute using Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app to do some calculations. To test if the calculation function is correct, I prepared a series of CSV file as input and I want to check the output. So I put all of the csv file inside a folder called data inside the android studio project folder. But when i tried to find the folder and list all of the files inside the folder, it shows that the folder cannot be found. I attached the code that used to get the files [get files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWL35.png) and the main activity code[Main activity code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPB8u.png), and the output[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPpAi.png).

I want to test the code on pc and then installed it on Android Phone. So I used the absolute path on my PC.

Is there anyone have some suggestions? Any help are appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Following is my read file code:

```
public Object[] createFolderList_rev001() {
        ArrayList<String> Pelvis_filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> R_thigh_filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> R_shank_filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> L_thigh_filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> L_shank_filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.i(TAG, "Folder finding......");
        try {
            //Create a file object
            File folder = new File("/Users/Aria_Z/AndroidStudioProjects/QZ_APP_V1/app/assets");
            if (!folder.exists() || !folder.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("folder cannot found");
                Log.i(TAG, "folder not found");
            } else {
                System.out.println("folder exist");
                Log.i(TAG, "folder exist");
            }
            //Get all the names of the files present in the given directory
            File[] files = folder.listFiles();
            System.out.println("length: " + files.length);
            for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
                if (files[i].getName().contains("D422CD000561")){
                    Pelvis_filenames.add(files[i].getName());
                }else if(files[i].getName().contains("D422CD000566")){
                    R_thigh_filenames.add(files[i].getName());
                }else if(files[i].getName().contains("D422CD000553")){
                    R_shank_filenames.add(files[i].getName());
                }else if (files[i].getName().contains("D422CD00053A")){
                    L_thigh_filenames.add(files[i].getName());
                }else if (files[i].getName().contains("D422CD001764")){
                    L_shank_filenames.add(files[i].getName());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Object[] folderList = new Object[]{Pelvis_filenames, R_thigh_filenames,R_shank_filenames,L_shank_filenames,L_thigh_filenames};
        return folderList;
    }
```

Following is my main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Object[] folderList = createFolderList_rev001();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please post source code as **text**, not images. The filesystem path shown in your first screenshot is a filesystem path on your development machine. It is not a filesystem path on your Android phone. Your Android code, running on your Android phone, cannot access files on your development machine. To package data in your app, that your app can then read in, please [use raw resources or assets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourceTypes).

Comment: 1) you are forcing people to read text as you formatted (e.g. font, size and color, BACKGROUND {light gray on dark gray!!}); 2) you are *disabling* people to copy&paste your code (to test or debug, ...) || Please check [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16320675)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I run this code on my PC, so I write the absolute filesystem path on my pc. Is this wrong? I want to test if my code is correct. If it is correct and then I will installed it on Android phone.